# Traefik not working with more than 3 ports exposed

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to get email service working with traefik. I need to expose 25, 100, 143.. etc.

But traefik only works with <= 3 ports. If I add more than 3, it it stopped working.
This is my sample config:

```
networks:
      - traefik-net
    environment:
      - HTTPS=OFF
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - "traefik.backend=mail"
        - "traefik.port=80"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mail.mydomain.com"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"

        - "traefik.mail.port=80"
        - "traefik.mail25.port=25"
        - "traefik.mail110.port=110"
        - "traefik.mail143.port=143"
        - "traefik.mail465.port=465"
        - "traefik.mail587.port=587"
        - "traefik.mail993.port=993"
        - "traefik.mail995.port=995"
```

I didnt see anything unnormal in mail and traefik service log.
Can anyone help me? Thank in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for you interest in the project.

Thanks to the addtional information you gave on [Github](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2336) and after analyzing your problem, it appears you try to expose in **HTTP** ports which have to be accessed  in**SMTP(S), POP3(S) and IMAP(S)** (which are over **TCP**).

Currently Træfik is only a HTTP Reverse Proxy and you can't do TCP calls through it, your use case can't work for the moment.